# Get polygon from longitude and latitude in mobile apps

Tags: android, gis, mapbox, postgis

I am working on an app that have over 2 millions of user. It is going to introduce location based feature. From the very beginning we want to provide the user a location based notification which will be changed based on their location/region. I am using PostGIS and Mapbox technologies. I have a custom polygon which is the indicator of different region. I know I can use a ST_Within of PostGIS to get the polygon info by sending longitude and latitude to server everytime. I am using the folloing function to get the region

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getRegion(getlng numeric, getlat numeric, OUT outregion text)
    as $$
BEGIN
     SELECT region into outregion
     FROM mypolygon 
     WHERE ST_Within(
         ST_GeometryFromText(
             'POINT('|| getlng ||' '|| getlat ||')', 4326
         ),
     geom);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

and calling the function by

```
SELECT getRegion(getlng, getlat);
```

But as there are millions of user it will increase the load on database server and need to be increased the TPS. Is there any other way to get the polygon/region from point beside using postgis directly? The region polygon is changable, not constant.

There is a method called [ray-casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) and recently mapbox is supporting [query](https://github.com/mapbox/vtquery) withing vector tiles. Is ray-casting or query within vector tiles will be a better approach for doing the same thing? (Again remember, the polygon is not constant.)

In a nutshell, I actually want to know the best practices using currently by the community to reduce the load on server and save time.

Comment: Quick questions: how do your indexes look like? how large is the table `mypolygon`?

Comment: 14 MB shapefile. 8-10 MB table space in postgres

Answer (score 2):

1) You will have to index your polygons using some grid (may be UTM, Google tiles or your own custom grid)

2) Identify grid of user location

3) Now fetch the polygons which lie on the same grid .In the best case you will get only single polygon and you will not have to use ST_Within.

4) Now if you get multiple polygons use ST_Within with only these polygons instead of the entire list of polygons

This Algo will save lot of memory and processing as ST_Within is a very heavy process.

Note: I have been using this approach from past 4 years and it has done wonders in terms of time and memory saving

Comment: can you please elaborate no 1 little bit in details. How can I Identify GRID of App User without a PostGIS operation? Is there any way to get the GRID from App (both iOS or Android)

Comment: You will need to write android version for https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmap-tile-generator/source/default/source. 
Use method :  gmap-tile-generator/trunk/gmaps-tile-creator/src/gov/ca/maps/tile/geom/GlobalMercator.java  >>> public int[] GoogleTile(double lat, double lon, int zoom) This methods returns tile grid

Comment: Above is link to code of Google tile grid.  Below is a sample custom grid example:
 public static double[] getGrid(double latitude, double longitude, double degreeLat, double degreeLon) {
  double lonRem = (longitude % degreeLon);
  double latRem = (latitude % degreeLat);
  longitude = longitude - lonRem;
  latitude = latitude - latRem;
  return new double[] { latitude, longitude };  

   public static void main(String[] args) {
  double[] grid = getGrid(22.0, 81.0, 5.0, 10.0);
  System.out.println(grid[0] + "   " + grid[1]);
 }